# c# MDI parent form + login form error

Tags: c#, winforms, dispose

I get this error:

Starting a second message loop on a single thread is not a valid operation. Use Form.ShowDialog instead.

When trying to exit my app after disposing a login form. To clarify, this is what I'm doing in my form:

```
    public frmMainMDI()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        frmLogin frmLogin_ = new frmLogin(); //create new login form
        frmLogin_.ShowDialog(); //show i
        if (frmLogin_.DialogResult == DialogResult.Cancel) //if user pressed cancel
        {
            frmLogin_.Dispose(); //dispose login form
            Application.Exit(); //Exit application. If I used this line, it throws the error stated above in Program.cs
            //this.Dispose(); //If I try to use this one instead, it throws an 'already disposed' error
            //this.Close(); //same error as .dispose
        }
        else
        {
            intCurrentLoggedInStaffID = frmLogin_.intStaffID;
        }
    }
```

And this is in my program.cs:

```
    static void Main()
    {

        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new frmMainMDI()); //this is the line that bugs out

    }
```

I don't quite get it. It almost looks like the app is trying to restart itself when I try to `.Exit` it. Am I missing something pretty fundamental here? (I'm guessing the answer is 'yes')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're attempting to exit the application (which means shut down the main message loop) in the middle of a constructor (which is bad in general) which is being run in the method which is supposed to be starting up that message loop in the first place.  So you have contradictory operations going here.

What I would suggest is that you move your login form/dialog code into your program.cs/Main() function.  So something like this:

```
static void Main()
{

    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

    using(frmLogin frmLogin_ = new frmLogin()) { //create new login form
       frmLogin_.ShowDialog(); //show i
       if (frmLogin_.DialogResult == DialogResult.Cancel) //if user pressed cancel
       {
           return; // This exits your application
       }
    }

    Application.Run(new frmMainMDI()); //this is the line that bugs out

}
```

Comment: Try your code before posting it.  This one bombs.  Move the Application init calls before the using statement.

Comment: Sorry, was just "splicing" his stuff together without paying enough attention.  I fixed it.

Comment: This works perfect, thanks. I completely failed to realise I was in the constructor!

Answer (score 1):

I can't quite explain why you are getting this error, but I can suggest a better way to do it. If I understand your intentions correctly, you want to show a login form before the main MDI window is shown and exit your application, if the user pressed cancel in the login form.

Your program.cs:

```
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        LoginForm loginForm = new LoginForm();
        if (loginForm.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.Cancel)
        {
            MainMdiForm mainMdiForm = new MainMdiForm();
            mainMdiForm.intCurrentLoggedInStaffID = loginForm.intStaffID;
            loginForm.Dispose();
            loginForm = null;
            Application.Run(mainMdiForm);
        }
    }
```

Your constructor in the MainMdiForm should only contain the call to `InitializeComponents`.

Comment: @Daniel: Note that you're holding a reference to a LoginForm instance for the lifetime of the app (the UI thread specifically).

Comment: @Tergiver: Nope. I dispose it just before I show the MDI window and it is not used afterwards. The optimizer should flag it for garbage collection right after the call to Dispose.

Comment: @Daniel: That sounds like voodoo magic to me. I wasn't aware that the CLR had intimate knowledge about "disposal status". IDisposable is an interface, not a bit hidden away in instance memory. I could be wrong. Do you have evidence?

Comment: @Tergiver: No, I don't have evidence and I didn't mean that the garbage collector knows about the Dispose state. What I meant was: (1) I release all resources of the form with the call to Dispose, so no problems with it anymore. (2) Furthermore, after the call to dispose, the form isn't used anymore, that's why I **guessed** that the optimizer can flag it for garbage collection early. Even if that guess is wrong, the call to Dispose should free all critical resources. But you can assign null to loginForm, just to be sure... I updated my answer, so I don't look stubborn ;-)

Comment: @Daniel: It's true that calling Dispose will release any *external* (i.e. unmanaged) resources, or at least that's its purpose. But you still have a reference to a chunk of managed memory sitting at the top of the stack (as this is the Main method which doesn't exit until the Application.Run call does--after mainMdiForm is closed). Setting `loginForm = null` will solve it. I'm not trying to be a jerk, just making a reminder that while garbage collection frees you from having to manage memory, it doesn't free you from having to manage your references.

Comment: @Tergiver: Well, you *are* being a jerk, but that's ok! ;-) I am being one myself on topics I find important, and obviously it is and you thought further than I did!